# In Common Lisp (SBCL), is there a way to examine the individual parts of an atom?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

For example, if I had the atom 'ABCD, is there a way to determine the individual characters that make up the atom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the list of characters in the symbol:

```
(coerce (string 'ABCD) 'list) ; => (#\A #\B #\C #\D)
```

You can perform any sort of usual string analysis on a symbol if you first convert it:

```
(string 'ABCD)                ; => "ABCD"
(char (string 'ABCD) 0)       ; => #\A
(subseq (string 'ABCD) 0 2)   ; => "AB"
```

Answer (score 11):

Those characters do not "make up an atom" (an atom is something different; roughly "not a list").

What you have there is a *symbol*.  A symbol has a name, by which it is referred to.  You can get the name of a symbol with the function `symbol-name`:

```
CL-USER > (symbol-name 'ABCD)
=> "ABCD"
```

(Note that both `symbol-name` and `ABCD` denote symbols, but `symbol-name` is evaluated whereas `ABCD` is not due to the quote—the above is read the same as `(symbol-name (quote ABCD))`.)

Symbols also have other properties, which you can get by the functions `symbol-package`, `symbol-plist`, `symbol-value`, or `symbol-function`.

For an overview, take a look at [chapter 10 of the Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/10_.htm).